# Shell script command output in if condition comparison fails to compare to same value string

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, shell

I'm incorporating a script snippet which determines Android version via:
`adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`
which returns: `4.1.2` or `4.0.4`

The snippet currently looks like this:

```
if [ "$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release)" == "4.1.2" ]; then
    rw_path="/sdcard/"
elif [ "$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release)" == "4.0.4" ]; then
    rw_path="/data/local/"
fi
echo $rw_path
```

I thought adb might return the value via stderr just as it does with push/pull output so I tried this as well (not sure if that's the right way of doing this though):

```
if [ "$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release 2>&1)" == "4.1.2" ]; then
    rw_path="/sdcard/"
elif [ "$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release 2>&1)" == "4.0.4" ]; then
    rw_path="/data/local/"
fi
echo $rw_path
```

Tried -eq operator instead of == but it warns that "integer expression expected".

I then tried this to make sure it actually compares something:

```
version=$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release 2>&1)
if [ "$version" == "4.1.2" ]; then
    rw_path="/sdcard/"
elif [ "$version" == "4.0.4" ]; then
    rw_path="/data/local/"
fi
echo $version
echo $rw_path
```

Tried unquoting `"$variable"` to no luck. The above outputs "4.0.4" or "4.1.2" for `$version` as expected but in all the attempts above it fails to output anything for `$rw_path`.

What am I doing wrong?!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Tried double brackets as suggested below with no luck. How come "4.0.4" output is not equal to "4.0.4" string? Is whitespace relevant in comparison? Can I trim the output first? Just a thought...

Comment: Whitespace is relevant. Your script works ok, the problem is with what adb returns.

Comment: Try echo "-$rw_path-" to see if returned string has some whitespaces in it.

Comment: Tried that and only the first dash was returned which confirmed that adb returns a new line at the end just as Mark Wagner said. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect there is an "\r" in the output of the `adb` command. Try

`$(adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release | tr -d '\r')`

Comment: Superb! You're a genius. I'll remember that!

Comment: god bless you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try making those brackets around your test double brackets.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help.